# http server push to trigger an action

Tags: perl, browser, timer, server-push

I am trying to implement server push where in some action can be triggered based on a time interval elapsed in the server. I thought of doing it this way as I do not have to take care of the javascript timer , browser dependency, users disabling javascript.
I tried CGI::Push, but I am not sure how can i trigger an event using it. Say If I want to submit the form based on some response received from server.
If there is some better way to initiate time controlled events, I am looking for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to make a browser perform an action:

- User activity
- Client-side javascript
- HTTP 301 redirection
- HTML meta refresh/redirection

However, as far as I'm aware only the first two (user activity and client-side javascript) can submit a form, and only javascript can interact with the server automatically. So if the user has javascript disabled, you can't make their browser do something -- which is kind of the reason why people disable javascript in the first place.

Comment: or may be even if the javascript is disabled, we send a popup where in some message and submit button is there after timeout. and user has to submit the form himself even if js is disabled. but how can i keep the values entered in form. what you say about it

Comment: Popups normally require javascript too. Maybe you could have an iframe notification area using HTML meta to refresh itself every minute, and when it's time for the "popup" you can update it with a message saying, "Please submit now."

Comment: Tom instead of iframe if i want to trigger from submit using javascript, how can that be done based on timed server response.

Comment: Same idea really. Set up some javascript to periodically check the server. When the time comes, the server responds with a javascript snippet to submit the form. Javascript frameworks make this straightforward, e.g. Prototype's "PeriodicalUpdater" object.

Comment: for now I have fixed it with javascript interval. i shall not allow the user to use the app if js is not enabled. will do more research to have it done more standard way. thanks for your ideas